# Быстродействие считывания

Tags: delphi, benchmark, c++

Вообщем написаны 2 программы на Delphi и на C++ , провожу абсолютно однотипные операции( считываю массив длинною 10 ^ 7) но почему то Delphi это делает на целую секунду быстрее, кто может ответить в чем причина? и как можно ускорить в C++ ввод и вывод данных??
[image]

Вот программы, на Си и на Delphi

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int n;
short a[10000000];

int main()
{
    freopen("output.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("input.txt", "w", stdout);

    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%hd", &a[i]);   
    printf("1");

    return 0;   
}
```

---

```
var n, i : integer;
      a : array[1..10000000] of shortInt;

begin
    reset(input, 'output.txt');
    rewrite(output, 'input.txt');

    ReadLn(n);
    for i := 1 to n do
      Read(a[i]);
    WriteLn('1');

    close(input);
    close(output);
end.
```

Испытание 2.
  теперь первым выполняется exe - шник на c++ и в дельфи for заменен на while! все остальное то же.

[image]

```
    var n, i : integer;
      a : array[1..10000000] of Integer;

begin
    reset(input, 'output.txt');
    rewrite(output, 'input.txt');

    ReadLn(n);
    i := 1;
    while ( i <= n ) do
    begin
      Read(a[i]);
      inc(i);
    end;
    WriteLn('1');

    close(input);
    close(output);
end.
```

Comment: Сделайте на чистом Си и посмотрите результат. Думаю, он удивит еще больше. К тому же нельзя проводить опыты так, т.к. скажется буферизация файла операционной системой. Если дельфовая программа стартовала вторая - вот вам и "ускорение"

Comment: на Си откомпилировал работает еще дольше, почти 3 секунды, почему так? я ожидал что будет быстрее

Comment: Может разница в том что C++ (сужу по JS не уверен) при каждой интеграции цикла проверяет условие а в Delphi число интераций заранее определено. Попробуйте (не будете же вы в C++ в исходном файле прописывать 10^7 вызовов ф-ций) использовать в Delphi проверяемые циклы например repeat...until while...do и скажите результат (мне тоже интересно :) )

Comment: @Евгений536, прогнал у себя C/C++ 

    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 
    Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 avp avp 78888899 дек.  24 16:26 output.txt

Время C и С++ в общем одинаково. От запуска к запуску real меняется от 2.17 до 2.19 сек. Т.о. около 40Мбайт/сек.

А у Вас какое время?

--

Пардон, посмотрел  в таблицу в вопросе и увидел 2.6 сек против 1.6 в Дельфи. 

А на Си у Вас стабильно дольше? Иногда время "плавает", надо смотреть несколько запусков. Я попробовал еще раз и Си и С++ с -O3, естественно тоже самое (оптимизация не влияет) от 2.14 до 2.33 сек.

Comment: @Евгений536, что вы гадаете на кофейной гуще? Я уже сказал: "нажмите кнопку "View CPU" в Delphi и аналогичную в компиляторе c++" (если там такая есть у вас). И посмотрите, что там происходит. Даже если вы не знаете assembler банально посчитайте количество строк в циклах.

Comment: посмотрел я в View CPU и также закрыл его, потому что ничего не понимаю...! На Си и на С++ незначительное изменение, на 2 миллисекунды разница вообщем!

Comment: @Евгений536 А вы правда получаете удовольствие от бенчмарков бессмысленных последовательностей операций?

Comment: нет, я просто недавно писал олимпиаду и столкнулся с тем, что задача не прошла, когда я считывал таким образом cin >> a[i], то миллион чисел считывались дольше 2 секунд...! когда я изменил это на scanf("%d" &a[i]); то программа еле уложилась в секунду...! что очень меня удивило. Теперь задался вопросом как можно и это ускорить, ведь Delphi может быстрее и намного быстрее

Comment: ну вы, конечно, гоните... Код высокоуровневых языков всегда преобразуется к низкоуровневым! и код каждого высокоуровневого языка преобразуется по-разному! те есть, это все равно, что сравнивать время запуска системы на двух разных машинах. Видимо компилятор Делфи преобразует данный код в  меньшее количество низкоуровневых команд (если выразиться попроще, не вдаваясь в длительность выполнения каждой из команд)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Все очень просто. В случае с делфи, компилятор знает, что вызов Read будет читать число. И только его. И может вставить правильный код сразу.

В случае с scanf ситуация не столь проста. Как минимум каждый раз будет делаться парсинг строки формата. А это как не оптимизируй - медленно.

Что же делать?

- писать свой парсер. Но как то не то.
- использовать готовые парсеры, например boost.spririt
- также, по ссылкам ниже, народ пишет, что если читать строку, а потом преобразовывать с помощью atoi, то получается в 4 раза быстрее.

полезные ссылки

- [Снова про ввод/вывод в C++](http://codeforces.ru/blog/entry/5217)
- [scanf не предназначен для ввода большого кол-ва информации](http://www.amse.ru/courses/cpp1/2010.03.03.html)
- [sprintf/sscanf и скорость - понятия совместимые ?](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/339303.flat)
- [рассуждают о том же](http://codeforces.ru/blog/entry/10)

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо, особенно teanЫЧ, немного да разобрался с этой проблемой, но больше всех ответов мне понравился у KoVadim!

Comment: @Евгений536, ну вы меня прямо в краску вогнали

Comment: @Евгений536, это правильный ответ. Я тоже попробовал ускорить, смю в ответе 0.48 сек.

Answer (score 8):

Хотите быстро? Тогда забудьте об "удобных" функциях во **внутреннем цикле.**

Вот, например

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define fatal(msg) ({fprintf(stderr,"%s: %m",(msg)); exit(-1);})

int n;
short a[10000000];

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int in = open ("output.txt", O_RDONLY);
  if (in == -1)
    fatal("open output.txt");

  //  freopen("input.txt", "w", stdout);

  struct stat st;
  fstat (in,&st);
  printf ("len = %ld\n",(long)st.st_size);
  char *file = (char *)mmap(NULL,st.st_size,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,in,0),
    *p;
  if (!file)
    fatal("mmap");
  madvise(p,st.st_size,MADV_SEQUENTIAL);
  n = strtol(file,&p,10);
  printf ("n = %d\n",n);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    while (*p <= ' ')
      p++;
    a[i] = 0;
    while (*p >= '0') 
      a[i] = a[i]*10 + (*p++ - '0');
  }

  printf ("i = %d, a[%d] = %d\n",i,i-1,a[i-1]);
  exit(0);
}

avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc -O3 mapio.c -o mapio
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ tail -5 output.txt 
9999995
9999996
9999997
9999998
9999999
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat input.txt 
1 -27009
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ time ./mapio 
len = 78888899
n = 10000000
i = 10000000, a[9999999] = -27009

real    0m0.478s
user    0m0.180s
sys 0m0.228s
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

tail показывает конец входного файла, а в Вашу программу я вставил печать последнего элемента a[], введенного scanf(), чтобы убедиться в результате своей программки.

Сейчас попробую просто прочесть весь файл read-ом вместо mmap-а.

**Дополнение**

Код меняем так

```
#if 0
  char *file = (char *)mmap(NULL,st.st_size,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,in,0),
    *p;
  if (!file)
    fatal("mmap");
  madvise(p,st.st_size,MADV_SEQUENTIAL);
#else
  char *file = malloc(st.st_size), *p;
  if (read (in,file,st.st_size) != st.st_size)
    fatal("read");
#endif
```

Получаем

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc -O3 mapio.c -o mapio
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ time ./mapio 
len = 78888899
n = 10000000
i = 10000000, a[9999999] = -27009

real    0m0.989s
user    0m0.144s
sys 0m0.728s
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Comment: Дополнил сравнением с read вместо mmap

Comment: Ахиреть, интересно будет разобраться! я завтра просмотрю все это и отпишусь! сегодня просто времени нету...! спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ха-ха паренек по неопытности работает на домашней Windows машине со старичком Delphi, а вы ему впаяли пачку системных вызовы *nix ядра не имеющих прямых аналогов у Microsoft. Ставлю сотню нефти что он ни черта в этом не поймет.
P.S. Плюсую за код.

Comment: Паренек в своем комментарии (где-то выше) говорил об олимпиаде. Так, что IMHO он этим делом интересуется.

Значит прочтет man mmap, почитает (или спросит) про виртуальную память, области ядра и пользователя и т.д. 

Поймет! Потом для винды наверное адаптирует (там вроде тоже маппинг файлов есть).

Comment: >а вы ему впаяли пачку системных вызовы *nix ядра не имеющих прямых аналогов у Microsoft

@igumnov, интересно, а в каком это месте у `Microsoft` нет аналогов `mmap`? А как же [File Mapping](https://www.google.com/search?q=File+Mapping+windows)? К тому же, самый быстрый способ взаимодействия с большими **последовательными** объемами информации - не `file mapping`, а работа с содержимым этого файла в страничном режиме подкачки прямиком в физическую память: [AWE](https://www.google.com/search?q=AWE+Windows). Но это будет вообще финиш, если не отделить оптимизацию от самого алгоритма.

Comment: да, если честно ничего не понял, но очень интересно! а когда попробовал на C++ запустить то указывал на ошибку в mman! если не сложно можно прокомментировать строки кода! P.s. я только второй месяц на C++ пишу, поэтому большого опыта и знаний в нем нет! Заранее спасибо

Comment: @mega Вы не так меня поняли. Я имею в виду что аналоги то есть, но чтобы заставить код @avp работать в Windows нужно все равно вручную заменить mmap на соответствующий заголовок из WinAPI с чем ТС и столкнулся.
 
>когда попробовал на C++ запустить то указывал на ошибку в mman!

У него просто нету хедера mman.h

По поводу AWE ничего сказать не могу так как никогда не работал с этим.

Comment: @Евгений536, Вы `man 2 mmap` прочтите. Если что-то после этого будет непонятно - спрашивайте. Постараюсь растолковать.

Comment: @avp: извините, что пришлось упомянуть ваш код в переписке с нашей «достопримечательностью».

Answer (score 5):

Подозреваю что си код

```
scanf("%hd", &a[i]);
```

делает больше чем паскаль код

```
Read(a[i]);
```

Думаю как минимум на разбор входной строки.

Answer (score 3):

На `StackOverflow` есть совершенно замечательный (по объёму проведённой работы) вопрос на похожую тему: [Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python)

Основная идея там в том, что `cin` и `stdio` в `С++` по умолчанию синхронизированы и из-за этого отключается буферизация. Надо делать

```
cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Подробно про это - там, в первом ответе. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Профилирование программ, тем более на разных языках - почти искусство:)
Однако - необходимость.

Когда-то (10 лет назад) тестировал компиляторы на разных тестах:
[Один из видов тестов](http://s06.radikal.ru/i179/1212/ee/a3bc91737182.png)